# js make object from string

Tags: javascript, string, object

i have to make a object from array then i can work with it letter.
i am trying this code it work's but output getting only last one

```js
let datas = "team1 1, team2 2, team3 3";

let teamdata = datas.split(" ");

var myObj = (function () {
  var result = { Tname: null, count: null };
  datas.split(/\s*\,\s*/).forEach(function (el) {
    var parts = el.split(/\s* \s*/);
    result.Tname = parts[0];
    result.count = parseInt(parts[1]);
  });
  return result;
})();

console.log(myObj);
```

output getting `{ Tname: 'team3', count: 3 }`

need output

```js
[{name: "team1", count: 1},
{name: "team2", count: 2},
{name: "team3", count: 3}]
```

Comment: You are overwriting the properties of `result` on every iteration, leaving you with the value of the last iteration.

Comment: *"i have to make a object"* - And you are successfully making an object.  But then you claim that the output you need is an **array**, not an object.  Shouldn't you be making an array then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, You could do it with
[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let datas = "team1 1, team2 2, team3 3";
let teamdata = datas.split(", "); // ['team1 1', 'team2 2', 'team3 3']
let result = teamdata.map(team=>({team:team.split(/\s+/)[0],count:+team.split(/\s+/)[1]}))
console.log(result);
```

expected *output*:

```js
[{name: "team1", count: 1},
{name: "team2", count: 2},
{name: "team3", count: 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have to make a object

But you then claim that your expected output is an *array*, not an object:

```
[
  {name: "team1", count: 1},
  {name: "team2", count: 2},
  {name: "team3", count: 3}
]
```

In that case, make an array and then `.push()` to that array within the loop:

```
var result = [];
datas.split(/\s*\,\s*/).forEach(function (el) {
  var parts = el.split(/\s* \s*/);
  result.push({
    Tname: parts[0],
    count: parseInt(parts[1])
  });
});
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
let datas = "team1 1, team2 2, team3 3";

var results = [];
var myObj = (function () {
  var result = { Tname: null, count: null };
  datas.split(/\s*\,\s*/).forEach(function (el) {
    var parts = el.split(/\s* \s*/);
    result.Tname = parts[0];
    result.count = parseInt(parts[1]);
        results.push(result);
  });
  return results;
})();
console.log(results)
```

The problem with your code was that you successfully splitted the string and converted it to the object but as you are expecting the result to be in the array you were not storing the object rather were **rewriting the same object** time and again.